# How to create a sub frames with a specific layout?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm aiming to make a login program but the only part that confuses me is how to make the frames.I need 3 different frames but I neither know how to make a frame other the then like this:

```
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

and I can only make labels and widgets using that single mainframe. As far as making another one, it is beyond me. I need to know exactly place widets inside of each frame and even after creating frames I don't know how to place stuff on the grid. Would I go for the overall grid, or does something change after making the grid. I'm using the following layout for making the frame. Basically i'm hoping for a crash course in frames. Any information i've gathered doesn't make sense to me, even after I tried to put it into code.

[image]

I've got the coding part down just not the frame part.

```
#Import tkinter to make gui
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import codecs

def login(*args
          ):
    file = open("rot13.txt", "r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    uname = user.get()
    pword = pw.get()

    for i in lines:
        x = i.split()
        if codecs.encode(uname,'rot13') == x[0] and codecs.encode(pword,'rot13') == x[1]:
            result.set("Successful")
            break;
        else:
            result.set("Access Denied")

root = Tk()
root.title("Login")

#Configures column and row settings and sets padding
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

user = StringVar()
pw = StringVar()
result = StringVar()

user_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, textvariable=user)
user_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

pw_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, textvariable=pw)
pw_entry.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Username ").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Password ").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="").grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Result").grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="").grid(column=1, row=5, sticky=W)

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Login", command=login).grid(column=3, row=6, sticky=W)

#Makes a spot to put in result
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=result).grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=(W, E))
#Opens up with item selected and allows you to enter username without having to click it
user_entry.focus()
#Runs calculate if click enter
root.bind('<Return>', login)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: A long explanation + a pretty image + a good-looking MCVE... But I still have not got what you really want to achieve: "... the only part that confuses me is how to make the frames.I need 3 different frames but I neither know how to make a frame other the then like this: ... As far as making another one, it is beyond me. I need to know exactly place widets inside of each frame and even after creating frames I don't know how to place stuff on the grid. Would I go for the overall grid, or does something change after making the grid." etc. What do these all (sentences) mean?

Comment: You want to get a view as in the image you've provided above? So what does prevent you to get there? Just make a few frames, put the right widgets in the right frames, and that's all.

Comment: What I want is to have three frames like those three boxes in the image. I want to put username and password widget in the first box result of the login in the second box and login button in the third box. What I want is to know how to put the widgets into the three boxes and how to create those three boxes(frames). I don't know how to make more than 1 frame. I try to make 1 big frame and then make three sub frames using that mainframe but none of my widgets show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the key point that you are missing is that subframes of mainframe use mainframe as the parent and that widgets within subframes use the subframe as parent.  Furthermore, you can then place the subframe within the mainframe and the subframe widgets within the subframe.  You do not have to pass parents to .grid because each widget knows its parent.  A simplified example:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
mainframe = Frame(root)
login = Frame(mainframe)
label = Label(login, text='label')
entry = Entry(login)
display = Frame(mainframe)
result = Label(display, text='display result')

mainframe.grid()  # within root
login.grid(row=0, column=0) # within mainframe
label.grid(row=0, column=0) # within login
entry.grid(row=0, column=1) # within login
display.grid()  # within mainfram
result.grid(row=2, column=0) # within display
```